# Scraped image not displaying using Simple_HTML_DOM

Tags: html, web-scraping, simple-html-dom, imdb

Alright. I am scraping a poster from IMDb, and for the life of me, I cannot figure out why it is not displaying — I just get a little question mark like the image is missing. This is my current code:

```
<?php    
$p = 1;
foreach($movie_html->find("div[class=image]") as $poster1)
{
    foreach($poster1->find("img") as $poster2)
    {
        $p++;
        if ($p == 1) break;
    }
}
$poster3 = $poster2->src;
?>

<img src="<?php echo($poster3); ?>" height="300"/>
```

When I simply `echo` the `$poster3` variable it returns the proper URL of the image (so I know that code is working like it should), but on the actual webpage, I don't see the image. Instead, all I get is a little question mark as if the image is not at the specified URL. When I right click on that box, and force Safari to open the image in a new tab, I see the image just sitting there all nice and pretty! But for some reason, it is not displaying on my site.

Any ideas? Is IMDb locking me out to prevent scrapers? Or is there something in my code?

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you?

```
<?php
/* getIMDB.php
   -- displays movie poster (and its url as a tool-tip) from an IMDB page
*/
    include_once('../simpleHTML/simple_html_dom.php');

    $url = "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0246578/";
    $movie_html = file_get_html($url);
    outputImg($movie_html);


function outputImg($movie_html)
{
    $p = 1;
    foreach($movie_html->find("div[class=image]") as $poster1)
    {
        foreach($poster1->find("img") as $poster2)
        {
            $p++;
            if ($p == 1) break;
        }
    }
    $poster3 = $poster2->src;
    echo "<img src='" . $poster3 . "' title='" . $poster3 . "'/>";
}
?>
```